# How to write cucumber step definition for sign up page with ref_id in its URL?

Tags: cucumber

I am trying to write a cucumber step definition when user visit sign up page through credit referral.The url of the sign up page contains the ref_id which is actually the user id of the referrer. How do I write step definition for -

When /^I visit sign up page with ref_id: "([^"]*)"$/ do |arg1|
  ....?????
end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out myself. Here's the web_step :

```
When /^I visit sign up page with ref_id "([^"]*)"$/ do |id|
  visit("/users/sign_up?ref_id=#{id}")      
end
```